# How do I implement a timer to deal each card after 2 seconds?

Tags: javascript

I have this function which will deal a card to a player, then to a dealer, then to a player and then to a dealer.

I have tried to use `setTimeout(function, milliseconds);` but it doesn't work. For example, if I set 2 seconds, it will wait for 4 seconds, then deal the 2 cards to the player and then straight away to dealer 2 cards or it will wait for 8 seconds, then in one batch deal all the cards out.

Here are my methods:

```
const dealOneCardToPlayer = () => {
    // Take a card from the top deck to be assigned to tempcard.
    tempCard = deck.cards.splice(0, 1);
    //console.log(tempCard);
    player.cards.push(tempCard);

    if (player.cards.length === 5) {
        player.canHit = false;
    }

    if (player.canHit) {
        $("#btnHit").show();
    } else {
        $("#btnHit").hide();
    }

    player.handValue = countHandValue(player.cards);
    makeCardPlayer(tempCard[0]);
}

const dealOneCardToDealer = (holeCard) => {
    // Take a card from the top deck to be assigned to tempcard.
    tempCard = deck.cards.splice(0, 1);
    dealer.cards.push(tempCard);

    if (dealer.cards.length === 5) {
        dealer.canHit = false;
    }

    if (dealer.canHit) {
        $("#btnHit").show();
    } else {
        $("#btnHit").hide();
    }

    dealer.handValue = countHandValue(dealer.cards);
    makeCardDealer(tempCard[0],holeCard);
}

const deal = () => {
    debugger;
    newDeck();

    // Option: to burn first card before deal a card
    // to the first player
    burnOneCard;

    dealOneCardToPlayer();
    dealOneCardToDealer(false);
    dealOneCardToPlayer();

    // true for hole card
    dealOneCardToDealer(true);

    showGameButtons(true);
    checkEndGame1();
    checkGameOver();
}
```

```html
<link href="check.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
    body{
        font-size: 2em;
    }

    h3, h5 {
        text-align: center;
    }

    h5{
        margin-top:-40px;
    }

    /*debugging purpose*/
    div#oneDeck {
        border: 1px solid green;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    /*debugging purpose*/
    div#playerCards {
        border: 1px solid blue;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    /*debugging purpose*/
    div#dealerCards {
        border: 1px solid red;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    #mainContainer {
        max-width: 600px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    fieldset {
        margin-top: 30px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        border-radius: 8px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px #999;
    }

    legend {
        background: #fff;
    }

    #cardContainerPlayer {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .card {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top; /*float: left;*/
        text-align: center;
        margin: 5px;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 70px;
        height: 100px;
        font-size: 26px;
        background-color: black;
        border: solid 1px black;
        color: white;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    .holeCard {
        /*visibility: hidden;*/
        border: solid 1px black;
        background: repeating-linear-gradient( 45deg, #606dbc, #606dbc 10px, #465298 10px, #465298 20px );
    }

    .red {
        background-color: red;
        border: solid 1px #8C001A;
    }

    .templatePlayer, .templateDealer {
        display: none;
    }

    #btnGame {
        margin: 10px;
    }

    .winner {
        border: solid 5px #7ac142;
    }

    .btnGame {
        background-color: dodgerblue; /* Green */
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 15px 32px;        
        /*border-radius:10px;*/
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
        transition-duration: 0.4s;
        box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    }

    #btnHit {
        margin-right: 20px;
    }

    .flex-container {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        max-width: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
        /*border: 1px solid red*/
    }

</style>
<h3>Simple Javascript BlackJack Game</h3>
<h5>developed by Steve Ngai</h5>
<div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="btnDevelopment">
        <input type='button' value='Create new Deck' onclick='newDeck();' />
        <input type='button' value='Burn a card' onclick='burnOneCard();' />
        <input type='button' value='Refresh Deck' onclick='showDeck();' />
        <input type='button' value='Deal a card to Player' onclick='dealOneCardToPlayer();' />
        <input type='button' value='Deal a card to Dealer' onclick='dealOneCardToDealer();' />
        <input type='button' value='Show hand value' onclick='showHandValue();' />
        <input type='button' value='Check end game' onclick='checkEndGame();' />
        <input type='button' value='Refresh deck remaining cards count' onclick='getDeckCardCount();' />
    </div>

    <fieldset id="deck">
        <legend>Remaining cards in the Deck: <span id="deckCardCount"></span></legend>
        <div id="oneDeck"></div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="containerDealer">
        <legend>Dealer (Hand Value: <span id="handValueDealer"></span>)</legend>
        <div style="width:30px">
            <svg class="checkmarkDealer" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52">
                <circle class="checkmark__circle" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none" />
                <path class="checkmark__check" fill="none" d="M14.1 27.2l7.1 7.2 16.7-16.8" />
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div id="dealerCards"></div>
        <div id="cardContainerDealer">
            <div class="card templateDealer">
                <span class="dealerCardFace"></span>
                <span class="dealerCardSuit"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="dealerCardsHandValue"></div>
    </fieldset>

    <div id="btnGame">
        <div class="flex-container">
            <div class="btn">
                <input type='button' class="btnGame" id="btnDeal" value='Deal' onclick='deal();' />
            </div>
            <div class="btn">
                <input type='button' class="btnGame" id="btnHit" value='Hit' onclick='hit();' />            
                <input type='button' class="btnGame" id="btnStand" value='Stand' onclick='stand();' />
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>

    <fieldset id="containerPlayer">
        <legend>Player (Hand Value: <span id="handValuePlayer"></span>)</legend>
        <div style="width:30px">
            <svg class="checkmarkPlayer" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52">
                <circle class="checkmark__circle" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none" />
                <path class="checkmark__check" fill="none" d="M14.1 27.2l7.1 7.2 16.7-16.8" />
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div id="playerCards"></div>
        <div id="cardContainerPlayer">
            <div class="card templatePlayer">
                <span class="playerCardFace"></span>
                <span class="playerCardSuit"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="playerCardsHandValue"></div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="result">
        <legend>Game Result</legend>
        <div id="gameResult"></div>
    </fieldset>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    "use strict";

    // Variable/Object declaration and initialization - Start
    const isDebug = false;
    const DELAY = 2000;
    var gameOver = false;
    const deck = {
        cards: []
    }

    var tempCard;
    const player = {
        cards: [],
        handValue: 0,
        isWinner: false,
        canHit: true
    }

    const dealer = {
        cards: [],
        handValue: 0,
        isWinner: false,
        canHit: true
    }

    var result = document.getElementById("gameResult");

    const cardSuit = ["hearts", "diams", "clubs", "spades"];
    const cardFace = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"];

    $(".checkmarkDealer").hide();
    $(".checkmarkPlayer").hide();
    $("#handValueDealer").hide();
    //Variable/Object declaration and initialization - End

    if (!isDebug) {
        document.getElementById("btnDevelopment").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("deck").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("oneDeck").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("playerCards").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("dealerCards").style.display = "none";
        //document.getElementById("result").style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("btnDevelopment").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("deck").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("oneDeck").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("playerCards").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("dealerCards").style.display = "block";
        //document.getElementById("result").style.display = "block";
    }

    const showGameButtons = (cardDealt) => {
        if (cardDealt) {            
            $("#btnDeal").hide();
            $("#btnHit").show();
            $("#btnStand").show();

            //document.getElementById("btnDeal").disabled = true;
            //document.getElementById("btnHit").disabled = false;
            //document.getElementById("btnStand").disabled = false;
        } else {            
            $("#btnDeal").show();
            $("#btnHit").hide();
            $("#btnStand").hide();

            //document.getElementById("btnDeal").disabled = false;
            //document.getElementById("btnHit").disabled = true;
            //document.getElementById("btnStand").disabled = true;
        }

        if (player.isWinner === true) {
            document.getElementById("containerDealer").classList.remove("winner");
            document.getElementById("containerPlayer").classList.add("winner");

            $("#handValueDealer").show();
            $(".checkmarkPlayer").show();
            $(".checkmarkDealer").hide();
        } else if (dealer.isWinner === true) {
            document.getElementById("containerPlayer").classList.remove("winner");
            document.getElementById("containerDealer").classList.add("winner");

            $("#handValueDealer").show();
            $(".checkmarkPlayer").hide();
            $(".checkmarkDealer").show();
        } else {
            
            
           
        }
    }
    showGameButtons(false);


    // In JavaScript, functions are objects.
    // You can work with functions as if they were objects.
    function card(suit, face) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.face = face;

        switch (face) {
            case "A":
                this.faceValue = 11;
                break;
            case "J":
            case "Q":
            case "K":
                this.faceValue = 10;
                break;
            default:
                this.faceValue = parseInt(face);
                break;
        }
    };



    const createDeck = () => {
        deck.cards = [];
        deck.cards.length = 0;
        cardSuit.forEach(function (suit) {
            cardFace.forEach(function (face) {
                deck.cards.push(new card(suit, face));
            });
        });
    }

    const shuffleDeck = () => {
        // Fisher–Yates shuffle algorithm
        let temp, i, rnd;
        for (i = 0; i < deck.cards.length; i++) {
            rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.cards.length);
            temp = deck.cards[i];
            deck.cards[i] = deck.cards[rnd];
            deck.cards[rnd] = temp;
        }
    }

    const newDeck = () => {
        createDeck();
        shuffleDeck();
        document.getElementById("oneDeck").innerHTML = "";

        player.cards = [];
        player.handValue = 0;

        dealer.cards = [];
        dealer.handValue = 0;

        var myNode = document.getElementById("cardContainerPlayer");
        var fc = myNode.firstChild.firstChild;

        while (fc) {
            myNode.removeChild(fc);
            fc = myNode.firstChild;
        }

        var myNodeDealer = document.getElementById("cardContainerDealer");
        var fcDealer = myNodeDealer.firstChild.firstChild;

        while (fcDealer) {
            myNodeDealer.removeChild(fcDealer);
            fcDealer = myNodeDealer.firstChild;
        }

        document.getElementById("playerCards").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("dealerCards").innerHTML = "";

        document.getElementById("oneDeck").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(deck);
    }

    const burnOneCard = () => {
        // Remove the top deck to burn
        deck.cards.splice(0, 1);
    }

    const showDeck = () => {
        document.getElementById("oneDeck").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(deck);
    }

    const dealOneCardToPlayer = () => {
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                // Take a card from the top deck to be assigned to tempcard.
                tempCard = deck.cards.splice(0, 1);
                //console.log(tempCard);
                player.cards.push(tempCard);

                if (player.cards.length === 5) {
                    player.canHit = false;
                }

                if (player.canHit) {
                    $("#btnHit").show();
                } else {
                    $("#btnHit").hide();
                }

                //player.cards.push(new card("Spades","A"));
                //player.cards.push(new card("Spades","10"));
                document.getElementById("playerCards").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(player);
                player.handValue = countHandValue(player.cards);
                document.getElementById("handValuePlayer").innerHTML = player.handValue;
                makeCardPlayer(tempCard[0]);
                resolve();
            }, DELAY);
        });
        
    }

    const dealOneCardToDealer = (holeCard) => {
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                // Take a card from the top deck to be assigned to tempcard.
                tempCard = deck.cards.splice(0, 1);
                dealer.cards.push(tempCard);

                if (dealer.cards.length === 5) {
                    dealer.canHit = false;
                }

                if (dealer.canHit) {
                    $("#btnHit").show();
                } else {
                    $("#btnHit").hide();
                }

                document.getElementById("dealerCards").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(dealer);
                dealer.handValue = countHandValue(dealer.cards);
                document.getElementById("handValueDealer").innerHTML = dealer.handValue;
                makeCardDealer(tempCard[0], holeCard);
                resolve();
            }, DELAY);
        });        
    }

    const hasAceInHand = (cardsOnHand) => {
        for (let key in cardsOnHand) {
            let arr = cardsOnHand[key];
            for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                let obj = arr[i];
                for (let prop in obj) {
                    if (prop === "face") {
                        if (obj[prop] === "A") {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    const countHandValue = (cardsOnHand) => {
        //console.log(hasAceInHand(cardsOnHand));
        let sum = 0;
        for (let key in cardsOnHand) {
            let arr = cardsOnHand[key];
            for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                let obj = arr[i];
                for (let prop in obj) {
                    if (prop === "faceValue") {
                        //console.log(prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
                        sum = sum + obj[prop];
                        debugger;
                        if (sum > 21 && hasAceInHand(cardsOnHand)) {
                            // Transfer Ace's face value from 11 to 1
                            sum = sum - 11; 
                            sum = sum + 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        return sum;
    }

    const showHandValue = () => {
        document.getElementById("playerCardsHandValue").innerHTML = player.handValue;
        document.getElementById("dealerCardsHandValue").innerHTML = dealer.handValue;
    }

    const getDeckCardCount = () => {
        document.getElementById("deckCardCount").innerHTML = deck.cards.length;
    }

    const checkGameOver = () => {
        if (gameOver) {
            $(".holeCard > :nth-child(1)").show();
            $(".holeCard > :nth-child(2)").show();

            $(".holeCard").removeClass("holeCard");
            $("#handValueDealer").show();

            showGameButtons(false);
        }

        
    }

    const checkEndGame1 = () => {
        gameOver = true;
        if (player.handValue === 21 && dealer.handValue !== 21) {
            result.innerHTML = "BlackJack! Player won.";
            player.isWinner = true;
        } else if (player.handValue !== 21 && dealer.handValue === 21) {
            result.innerHTML = "BlackJack! Dealer won.";
            dealer.isWinner = true;
        } else if (player.handValue === 21 && dealer.handValue === 21) {
            result.innerHTML = "Push.";
        } else {
            gameOver = false;
        }
    }

    const checkEndGame2 = () => {
        if (player.cards.length <= 5 && player.handValue > 21) {
            result.innerHTML = "Bust! Dealer won.";
            dealer.isWinner = true;
            gameOver = true;
        }
    }

    const checkEndGame3 = () => {

        if (player.cards.length <= 5 && dealer.cards.length <= 5) {
            // Check bust
            if (player.handValue <= 21 && dealer.handValue > 21) {
                result.innerHTML = "Bust! Player won.";
                player.isWinner = true;
            } else if (player.handValue === 21 && dealer.handValue !== 21) {
                result.innerHTML = "BlackJack! Player won.";
                player.isWinner = true;
            } else if (player.handValue !== 21 && dealer.handValue === 21) {
                result.innerHTML = "BlackJack! Dealer won.";
                dealer.isWinner = true;

            } else if (player.handValue === dealer.handValue) {
                result.innerHTML = "Push.";
            } else if (player.handValue > dealer.handValue) {
                result.innerHTML = "Player won.";
                player.isWinner = true;
            } else if (player.handValue < dealer.handValue) {
                result.innerHTML = "Dealer won.";
                dealer.isWinner = true;
            } else {
                result.innerHTML = "Error";
            }
        } else {
            result.innerHTML = "Error";
        }
        gameOver = true;
    }

    // This function use JQuery lib
    function makeCardPlayer(_card) {
        // .card is created in the template card css class
        var card = $(".card.templatePlayer").clone();

        card.removeClass("templatePlayer");

        // .cardFace is created in the template card css class
        // It will search for this css class and add the content aka innerHTML
        card.find(".playerCardFace").html(_card.face);

        // .suit is created in the template card css class
        // It will search for this css class and add the content aka innerHTML
        card.find(".playerCardSuit").html("&" + _card.suit + ";");
        // &spades; -> ♠, &clubs; -> ♣, &hearts; -> ♥, &diams; -> ♦
        // more char, https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_symbols.asp

        // hearts and diamonds are red color. otherwise, default black color.
        if (_card.suit === "hearts" || _card.suit === "diams") {
            card.addClass("red");
        }

        // option: replace previous card with new card (show one card all the time)
        $("#cardContainerPlayer").append(card);
    }

    // This function use JQuery lib
    function makeCardDealer(_card, _holeCard) {
        // .card is created in the template card css class
        var card = $(".card.templateDealer").clone();

        card.removeClass("templateDealer");

        // .cardFace is created in the template card css class
        // It will search for this css class and add the content aka innerHTML
        card.find(".dealerCardFace").html(_card.face);

        // .suit is created in the template card css class
        // It will search for this css class and add the content aka innerHTML
        card.find(".dealerCardSuit").html("&" + _card.suit + ";");
        // &spades; -> ♠, &clubs; -> ♣, &hearts; -> ♥, &diams; -> ♦
        // more char, https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_symbols.asp

        // hearts and diamonds are red color. otherwise, default black color.
        if (_card.suit === "hearts" || _card.suit === "diams") {
            card.addClass("red");
        }

        if (_holeCard) {
            card.addClass("holeCard");            
        }

        // option: replace previous card with new card (show one card all the time)
        $("#cardContainerDealer").append(card);

        $(".holeCard > :nth-child(1)").hide();
        $(".holeCard > :nth-child(2)").hide();
        
    }

    

    const deal = () => {
        debugger;
        newDeck();

        // Option: to burn first card before deal a card
        // to the first player
        burnOneCard;

        dealOneCardToPlayer()
            .then(dealOneCardToDealer)
            .then(dealOneCardToPlayer)
            .then(dealOneCardToDealer(true));

        //dealOneCardToPlayer();
        //dealOneCardToDealer(false);
        //dealOneCardToPlayer();

        //// true for hole card
        //dealOneCardToDealer(true);

        showGameButtons(true);
        checkEndGame1();
        checkGameOver();
    }

    const hit = () => {
        dealOneCardToPlayer();
        checkEndGame2();
        checkGameOver();
    }

    const stand = () => {
        // Recalculate dealer's hand value
        //dealer.handValue = countHandValue(dealer.cards);

        

        debugger;
        

        // Simple AI to automate dealer's decision to hit or stand
        if (dealer.handValue >= 17) {
            checkEndGame3();
        } else {
            // Hit until dealer's hand value is more than 16
            while (dealer.handValue < 17) {
                dealOneCardToDealer();
                checkEndGame3();
            }
        }
        checkGameOver();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You need two setTimeouts on the format `tId1 = setTimeout...; tId2=setTimeout

Comment: where's your attempt to use setTimeout? If you're saying it doesn't obey the timings you set, then potentially there's a logical error in what you tried - sounds like you maybe set both timeouts off at once, instead of making one wait for the other. But without seeing it, we can't say exactly what, or fix it for you.

Comment: I warmly recommend `async` / `await` here. With that you can easily `await timer(2000);` somewhere in the logic without having chaos

Comment: @ADyson ,  I have uploaded it at js.findingsteve.net/blackjack

Comment: @Steve eh? Update your code here please, where we can see it easily, and so the question makes sense. Thankyou. Use the "edit" button just under your blue "javascript" tag to do so. Off-site code does not count as a valid part of the question.

Comment: i have implemented promise as suggested with complete code and updated my original post

Comment: All you've done is add some CSS. It doesn't change the functionality at all. Do you actually understand what is being discussed here?

Comment: You ask me to upload the full code which I did.

Comment: Sorry I was looking at the question on mobile, which made it hard to see everything properly. Apologies.

Comment: Anyway, it seems to work as intended now? Is there anything still a problem?

Comment: No,  after the changes, my hit and stand function breaks. Still trying to figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the right way to approach is with promises:

```js
const DELAY = 2000;

function dealCardToPlayer() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) { 
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Dealing card to player');
      resolve();
    }, DELAY);
  });
}


function dealCardToDealer() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) { 
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Dealing card to dealer');
      resolve();
    }, DELAY);
  });
}

dealCardToPlayer()
  .then(dealCardToDealer)
  .then(dealCardToPlayer)
  .then(dealCardToDealer);
```

Comment: Hi, nice one. I tried. When I click Deal, it straight away deal one card to player and dealer with delay of 2 seconds. Then after that only, it delay for 2 seconds for both player and dealer. I have uploaded it at http://js.findingsteve.net/blackjack

Comment: @Steve the code shown here in this answer does not do that. You can run it here - press "run code snippet" above, and you can see how it works. It first waits for 2 seconds, then it deals a card, then it continues to deal them, with gaps of two seconds in between. If you tried to implement this answer, and got the result you've just described, then I assume you must have changed it somehow from what is shown here.

Comment: i have implemented promise as suggested with complete code and updated my original post